# Solr WebAdmin error 500

Tags: java, http, solr

it been days that I am trying to find a solution to start Solr 5.2.1 properly, but I always get this error :

> HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

```
Server Error
```

Caused by:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.authenticateRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:254)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Powered by Jetty://

Do you have any idea about it  ?
Thanks  a lot !

Update :

Whene I check the solr sevice status :

> service solr status

I get this too :

> Typically, this indicates a problem with the Solr server; check the Solr server logs for more information.
>           at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI$SolrResponseHandler.handleResponse(SolrCLI.java:502)
>           at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI$SolrResponseHandler.handleResponse(SolrCLI.java:492)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:222)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:164)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:139)
>           at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI.getJson(SolrCLI.java:527)
>           at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI.getJson(SolrCLI.java:471)
>           at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI$StatusTool.runTool(SolrCLI.java:659)
>           at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI.main(SolrCLI.java:215)

Comment: Do you mean version 5.2.1? I can't find any 5.1.2 version

Comment: Oh sorry ! yes 5.2.1 ! thx

Comment: How have you set up your instance? Using the install service script?

Comment: Yes,  everything was working fine! i just restarted the solr service !

Comment: Have you used the same user that you configured during install to restart the service? Sometimes if you've used the root to install and start then it causes a host of problems during subsequent runs using a non privileged user.

Comment: Solr was installed by user (solr) and restarted by root

Comment: I know that this shouldn't really make a difference since you're using root, but I would still suggest just trying to restart using the solr user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple dataimport jar version so Solr bugged to choose one ! 
I deteted the others. 
Thanks