# Rails with Solr + sunspot: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot

I have a Rails app (4.1.1) running in an Ubuntu instance under Apache + Phusion with SOLR (via [sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot))

THe app used to work well, but last week I upgraded the ubuntu (now it's on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS) and then SOLR stopped to work.
I start the server with the command

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
```

and the console outputs Successfully started Solr ...

```
Successfully started Solr ...
```

But when I tried to access it (example: to reindex the models, or even via browser, through http://myip:8983/solr) it outputs:

> HTTP ERROR 500 Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:
>
> ```
> Server Error Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.authenticateRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
> ```
>
> at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:179)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

anyone has any ideia of how I could start to work on this problem? I can't find anything relevant in the rails app log (/log/production.log) or in the Apache's error.log file.

Comment: did you read this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434823/solr-webadmin-error-500

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I dind't see this thread before. I took a quick read now after you posted, maybe there is some relation (the user access). The problem is that I don't run the solr instance through 'service solr start', instead I use the rake task from rails. I'll try to find something following this path, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing some `packages` in your Ubuntu 16?

what about this steps from the [documentation wiki](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Configure-Solr-on-Ubuntu,-the-quickest-way)

> ## Install Java (if not already installed)
>
> Because tomcat and solr are Java based softwares we need the Java environment (As it is advised in the Solr wiki : prefere a full JDK to a simple JRE.)

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

> Note : Working on Amazon EC2 instance, I had to upgrade temporarly my “micro” instance to “medium”, because of special memory needs during java’s installation.
>
> ## Install Tomcat & Solr (You can’t avoid this one)
>
> For ubuntu (tested with 10.4 LTS), there is an unique package to install, it will take care of installing both Tomcat & Solr, plus the integration of Solr in Tomcat.

```
$ sudo apt-get install solr-tomcat
```

> then let’s start the server

```
$ sudo service tomcat6 start
```

> Ok it is done !
>   Solr server responds at http://localhost:8080/solr
>   and the config & index will be stored at : /usr/share/solr/
>   In order to use it with Sunspot you’ll have to copy conf/schema.xml & conf/solrconfig.xml from your application to /usr/share/solr/ or /usr/share/solr/conf (Ubuntu 12.04).
>   But, indeed, you should read the tutorial further to understand why you shouldn’t use Solr directly.
>
> For now your data are stored in a folder of your system not dedicated to a specific user or application.
>   It is quite common to read that a public server should use a dedicated user account with constraint privileges. (internet is full of it)
>
> If like me your not totaly happy with it, follow the next steps to customize the whole thing. I won’t explain you how to start Tomcat as another user (Google it), but how to choose your Solr home directory